# Is there a way to prevent an Anchor tag from being a flex item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm really simplifying, but basically, I have this:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.subheader {
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.filler {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <div class="subheader">&lt;Some Text&gt;</div>
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

(I know I could use justify-content: space-between; but that is not the point)
The point is pretty simple: I have a flex-item, in the center, with some flex-item attributes to set.

However, sometimes, I'll want this center element to link somewhere, like so:

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;
    background: lightgreen;
}

.subheader {
    flex-grow: 2;
    text-align: center;
    border: 3px solid blue;
}

.filler {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="filler"></div>
    <a href="http://example.com">
        <div class="subheader">&lt;Some Text&gt;</div>
    </a>
    <div class="filler"></div>
</div>
```

As you can see by running the two snippets, in the second, the center element is way smaller. This is because the 'flex-grow: 2' attribute stopped working, because now, the *anchor* is the flex-item, not the division.

So, my question is, how can I "fix" this, without having to place the anchor elsewhere or add the flex-item attribute to the anchor manually?

- Is there a way to make it so that the anchor is "skipped" when the flex-container looks for flex-items, taking the division instead?
- Is it possible to "pass" the flex-item attribute to the anchor?

(Please note that, since this is merely an example/simplification, no, I cannot just "settle for an alternative that gives the same result")

Comment: display: contents; to `a`

Comment: Should I delete the question, or do I leave it?
Also, If I go in my inbox, the notification for your comment says "does this answer your question? <the name of the other question you linked>"

How do I answer/confirm?

Comment: no need to confirm, I have the privilege to close the question directly without confirmation. You can simply edit your question if you think the duplcate is not good or upvote the duplicate answer if it works for you ... you don't need to delete the quesiton, it can be useful for futur readers